# Get list of blobs under Virtual Directory in a Container and Azure Blobs

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-blob-storage

We have almost 100 virtual directories in a container. Now when we run the below code, it returns everything.

```
            foreach (IListBlobItem item in blobContainer.ListBlobs(null, false))
            {

                if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob))
                {
                    CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;
                }
            }
```

I'm hoping that if there is a way to get only blobs available under a specific virtual directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I found the solution by digging in the SDK.

```
                CloudBlobDirectory blobDirectory = blobContainer.GetDirectoryReference(relativeAddress);
            blobDirectory.ListBlobs();
```